# Javascript: How to display values of all radio buttons regardless of being checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have four radio buttons that I want to display all the values of using javascript. Supposedly, their elements are 1-4. How would I display the value of all four in a row together?

```
<input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="A" > Apples
<input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="B" checked Oranges
<input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="C" > Bananas
<input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="D" > Cherry
```

How would I display the values of all four in a row together separated by commas?

Every time I type in my code in Javascript to display this, it would only display the checked value and I don't know how to display the values for the others (A, C, D).

This is what I am typing in my code to try and display it:

```
var radiobuttons = document.andy.radiobutton.value + document.andy.radiobutton.value + document.andy.radiobutton.value;
ans.innerHTML = radiobuttons;
```

This just ends up repeading displaying the checked value several times and I want to display all values including the ones not checked in a row separated by commas. I'm confused on how to do so =(

Answer (score 0):

Using es6, below will work:

```
var values = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]'))
    .map(val => val.value) // creates an array of all values
    .join(); // joins the array to a string, separated by comma
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lmn80mc4/)</kbd>

or without es6, for older browsers:

```
var values = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]'))
    .map(function(val) { return val.value })
    .join();
```

In both cases then just do

```
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = values;
```

to get what you want.

<kbd>[DEMO with output in div](http://jsfiddle.net/Lmn80mc4/1/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that iterates over each radio button and fetched its checked status

```
var radiobuttons = document.andy.radiobutton;
var answer = [];

for (var i = 0; i < radiobuttons.length; i++) {
    answer.push(radiobuttons[i].value + ': ' + radiobuttons[i].checked);
}

document.getElementById('ans').innerHTML = answer.join(', ');
```